# How to group xml elements by element value using xslt

Tags: xslt

Im trying to group the xml using xslt ,I need it to be grouped based on 2 parameters value.
ShipFromLocationCode and ShipToLocationcode element value

if both match i need to group the xml child element with the matching parent element tags.

Sample input->

```
<ns1:Entity>
    <ns1:Load>
        <ns1:SystemLoadID>1</ns1:SystemLoadID>
        <ns1:ShipmentLeg>
            <ns1:Shipment>
                <ns1:ShipFromLocationCode>a</ns1:ShipFromLocationCode>
                <ns1:ShipToLocationCode>b</ns1:ShipToLocationCode>
                <ns1:Container>
                    <ns1:SystemContainerID>1</ns1:SystemContainerID>
                </ns1:Container>
            </ns1:Shipment>
        </ns1:ShipmentLeg>
        <ns1:ShipmentLeg>
            <ns1:Shipment>
                <ns1:ShipFromLocationCode>b</ns1:ShipFromLocationCode>
                <ns1:ShipToLocationCode>b</ns1:ShipToLocationCode>
                <ns1:Container>
                    <ns1:SystemContainerID>2</ns1:SystemContainerID>
                </ns1:Container>
            </ns1:Shipment>
        </ns1:ShipmentLeg>
        <ns1:ShipmentLeg>
            <ns1:Shipment>
                <ns1:ShipFromLocationCode>a</ns1:ShipFromLocationCode>
                <ns1:ShipToLocationCode>b</ns1:ShipToLocationCode>
                <ns1:Container>
                    <ns1:SystemContainerID>3</ns1:SystemContainerID>
                </ns1:Container>
            </ns1:Shipment>
        </ns1:ShipmentLeg>
        <ns1:Stop>
            <Stopex>1</Stopex>
        </ns1:Stop>
        <ns1:Stop>
            <Stopex>2</Stopex>
        </ns1:Stop>
    </ns1:Load>
</ns1:Entity>
```

Expected output->

```
<ns1:Entity>
    <ns1:Load>
        <ns1:SystemLoadID>1</ns1:SystemLoadID>
        <ns1:ShipmentLeg>
            <ns1:Shipment>
                <ns1:ShipFromLocationCode>a</ns1:ShipFromLocationCode>
                <ns1:ShipToLocationCode>b</ns1:ShipToLocationCode>
                <ns1:Container>
                    <ns1:SystemContainerID>1</ns1:SystemContainerID>
                    <ns1:SystemContainerID>3</ns1:SystemContainerID>
                </ns1:Container>
            </ns1:Shipment>
        </ns1:ShipmentLeg>
        <ns1:ShipmentLeg>
            <ns1:Shipment>
                <ns1:ShipFromLocationCode>b</ns1:ShipFromLocationCode>
                <ns1:ShipToLocationCode>b</ns1:ShipToLocationCode>
                <ns1:Container>
                    <ns1:SystemContainerID>2</ns1:SystemContainerID>
                </ns1:Container>
            </ns1:Shipment>
        </ns1:ShipmentLeg>
        <ns1:Stop>
            <Stopex>1</Stopex>
        </ns1:Stop>
        <ns1:Stop>
            <Stopex>2</Stopex>
        </ns1:Stop>
    </ns1:Load>
</ns1:Entity>
```

I have tried this using XSLT but it worked only for the shipment tag alone-

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

        <xsl:template match="*|text()|@*">
        
            <xsl:copy>
           
                 <xsl:for-each-group select="Shipment" group-by="concat(ShipFromLocationCode, '|', ShipToLocationCode)">
                <Shipment>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="ShipmentNumber, ShipFromLocationCode, ShipToLocationCode"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/Container"/>
                    
                </Shipment>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
           
            </xsl:copy>
           
      
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please don't post images of your data or code. Post the actual XML content in code blocks. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sounds like grouping with a composite key, so read an introduction and give it a try, show us what you have tried and how it failed if you get stuck; grouping intro is at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info

Answer (score 0):

Please insert your code as code samples, not as images.

As for your question, move the grouping code into a template

```
<xsl:template match="shipmentleg">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="shipment" group-by="..">..</xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and handle the rest of the nodes by other templates e.g. declare the identity transformation in XSLT 3 with `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` or spell it out in XSLT 2 as

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response - The XSLT code which i posted earlier it only works in case of input-<Entity><Shipment>.........</Shipment></Entity> so if i try to add any additional node in the input it fails.. also if i change template to this-> <xsl:template match="shipmentleg">it fails the condition only works if the template is like -><xsl:template match="*|text()|@*"> il try to rephrase my question so that it will be easier for you to understand